# Install Java 6 from Oracle to Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, software-installation, rpm, java, oracle

Since Java 6 is not available in Debian 5 I decided to take it from Oracle. I have downloaded Java 6 SDK in file jdk-6u45-linux-i586-rpm.bin. But how to install it?

I executed `jdk-6u45-linux-i586-rpm.bin` and got several files:

```
jdk-6u45-linux-i586.rpm                
sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm
sun-javadb-demo-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm
sun-javadb-docs-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm
sun-javadb-javadoc-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm
sun-javadb-client-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm
```

What I should do next?

UPD

After executing:

```
rpm -ivh jdk-6u45-linux-i586.rpm sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-demo-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-docs-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-javadoc-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-client-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm
```

got output:

```
/bin/basename is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/cat is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/cp is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/gawk is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/grep is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/ln is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/ls is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/mkdir is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/mv is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/pwd is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/rm is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/sed is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/sort is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/touch is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/cut is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/dirname is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/expr is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/find is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/tail is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/tr is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/wc is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/sh is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386
/bin/sh is needed by sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-demo-10.6.2-1.1.i386
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-docs-10.6.2-1.1.i386
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-javadoc-10.6.2-1.1.i386
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-client-10.6.2-1.1.i386
```

Comment: Java 6 from Oracle, I answered in the other answer you have the OpenJKD in Debian.

Comment: Why using debian 5 ? Buster will be out in few weeks

Comment: It is for special bedded device. Nobody will pay me for adopting newer Linux distribution

Comment: @Arpit in a few weeks?

Comment: It's in testing phase so i think it will be out soon

Comment: @Arpit I hope this won’t come as too much of a disappointment, but [that’s not what testing means](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting). We’re planning on releasing Debian 10 sometime in 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to install Oracle’s Java 6 JDK is to proceed as follows:

- install `java-package`:

  ```
  apt-get install java-package
  ```
- download `jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin` (**not** the RPM) from [the Oracle achives](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html);
- create the corresponding Debian package:

  ```
  make-jpkg jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin
  ```
- install the resulting package:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i oracle-java6-jdk_6u45_i386.deb
  ```

This will take care of setting up alternatives etc. so that you can fully replace any installed JVM. If you want to keep multiple JVMs installed, use `update-java-alternatives` to select the default JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install the rpms:

```
rpm -ivh jdk-6u45-linux-i586.rpm sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-demo-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-docs-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-javadoc-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-client-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm
```

should be enough, if you do not intend to do development, I would leave the demos `javadb-demo-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm` and the two doc packages out `sun-javadb-docs-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-javadoc-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm`.

Comment: After proceeding he command got many dependencies problems. Does it means it is mission impossible to install Java 6 in Lenny? More details in question body UPD.