# Strange dependencies when install Java 6 from Oracle to Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, java, dependencies

Trying to install Oracle Java 6 SDK to Debian Lenny. I have downloaded rpm file. After executing command

```
rpm -ivh jdk-6u45-linux-i586.rpm sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-demo-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-docs-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-javadoc-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm sun-javadb-client-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm
```

got output:

```
/bin/basename is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/cat is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/cp is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/gawk is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/grep is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/ln is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/ls is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/mkdir is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/mv is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/pwd is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/rm is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/sed is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/sort is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/touch is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/cut is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/dirname is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/expr is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/find is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/tail is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/tr is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/usr/bin/wc is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
/bin/sh is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386
/bin/sh is needed by sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-demo-10.6.2-1.1.i386
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-docs-10.6.2-1.1.i386
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-javadoc-10.6.2-1.1.i386
sun-javadb-common is needed by sun-javadb-client-10.6.2-1.1.i386
```

Why I got such strange dependencies? For example

```
/bin/ls is needed by jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.i586
```

I definitely have `ls` command on my system why Java install complains about it?

Comment: This is not duplicate because previous question was regarding install rpm while this one is about dependencies

Comment: Then I would suggest editing the dependency “update” out of the other question, otherwise it looks (to me) like a duplicate.

Comment: You are supposed to use `jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin` for an old 32bits OS → http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/cn/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html : Usually no extra dependencies.

Comment: On Debian and derived systems it is recommended to use "alien" to
convert RPM packages into .deb format instead of bypassing the Debian
package management system by installing them directly with rpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t (easily) install an RPM on Debian. Debian uses `dpkg`; RPM has its own package database and doesn’t know about anything you have installed on Debian. `rpm` is available in Debian, but that’s primarily to manipulate RPM packages, not to install them.

For Java in particular, you should use `java-package` instead to convert the `.bin` installer you can download from Oracle; see [my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448999/86440).