# Changing GNU Java 1.5 to Oracle Java 1.6

Tags: debian, software-installation, java

Trying to move from `GNU Java 1.5 to Oracle Java JDK 1.6` in my Debian Lenny. I have installed new Java into /opt/. But what I should do next? If I type java command I still have old one. I suppose I should create symlink `java -> /opt/JDK1.6/bin/java` instead of existing one   `java -> /etc/alternatives/java`. 
What else I should do?

Comment: Why not install the packaged Sun JDK from the Lenny repositories? I know you ran into issues trying to install them, but if you slowed down a bit and let people help you resolve your previous issues you’d probably find it better in the long run.

Comment: Because I have feeling that Lenny repositories will provide me with very old Java. Possible I'm wrong and I would be glad to do that. But how to install java 1.6 from Lenny repositories?

Comment: That’s a good point, the Lenny repositories only have 6u26. To install 6u45, see [my answer to one of your previous questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448999/86440). (This will also take care of setting up alternatives etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to change where `/etc/alternatives/java` points, use `update-alternatives`. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java <path to your java executable> 1
```

([Source.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492029/update-alternatives-install-says-it-needs-link-name-path-priority))

After you use the `--install` option, run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And select the one you just installed.

There's a better way than installing manually, though. If you use the [make-jpkg](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage) utility, you can create a .deb that can be installed with built-in tools.

Here's an example of how to do this:

First, download the JDK you want from oracle. You want the tar.gz format for the correct architecture. In this example, I'm using Java 8, but make-jpkg supports Java 6 too. Then run:

```
make-jpkg jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo dpkg -i jdk-8u171-linux-x64.deb
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Of course, there's also the OpenJDK Java packages, but I assume you have a good reason to use Oracle's Java.